# KivyMD: how to write text from file on screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am begginer and I try to make an app as a notes. Users can write their reminder in one screen.. it is written into a file, so I have a text in file, I want to show it on another screen.
I tried it something like this but it doesn´t work. Can anyone help me please?

```
class MyGoalsScreen (Screen):

   file= open("package.txt" , "r")
   load_file = ""
   for line in file:
       load_file = load_file + line
   file.close()
```

in .kv

```
<MyGoalsScreen>:
   name: "mygoals"  
   
   MDToolbar:
       title: "My Goals"
       pos_hint: {"top": 1} 
       
   
   MDCard:
       orientation: "vertical"
       pos_hint:{ "center_x" :0.5, "center_y": 0.5} 
       size_hint: 0.8, 0.7
       padding: "8dp"

       MDLabel:
           text: f"{load_file} "
           halign: "center"
           font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
           size_hint: 0.8, 0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:-

**.py code**

```
class MyGoalsScreen (Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        file= open("package.txt" , "r")
        load_file = ""
        for line in file:
            load_file = load_file + line
        file.close()
        self.ids.mylabel.text = load_file
```

**.kv code**

```
<MyGoalsScreen>:
    name: "mygoals"  

    MDToolbar:
        title: "My Goals"
        pos_hint: {"top": 1} 
   

    MDCard:
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint:{ "center_x" :0.5, "center_y": 0.5} 
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.7
        padding: "8dp"

    MDLabel:
        id: mylabel
        halign: "center"
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.1
```

I hope this resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `load_file` variable is in your python code not in your `.kv` file. To access something from the python file you have to use `app.`. So, instead of writing `load_file` use `app.load_file`. Also, you have to define load_file at the start of your py file. One more thing, as you define load_file at the start and then, later on change it. There are chances that it will not change in your kivy file as the data is already loaded on your screen. You have to refresh screen for that. I would suggest using python to add the text on the screen. You can give an `id` to your MDLabel and then use `id` to change the text. You have to do it like `self.root.ids.<MDLABEL_ID>.text = load_file`.